# Comparing neighbors of each element of an array with for-loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, indexing

I'm a new Python user and I'm finding the combination of Python+Numpy+Matplotlib amazing. I know a little of C and I've been asked to use Python in a work, everything was going well, Numpy has these incredible functions that can do almost everything I need. But I think I stepped on my first stone when I tried to use the "for-loop" with Numpy. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I believe my C logic is making me commit some mistakes.

Summarizing: I have one big array "A" (1D) made of 0 and 1 in a way that all 1 are together. I have another array "B" (256x9) with different conditions. What I want is to run trough the A array comparing all 8 neighbors of each A element with each of the first 8 columns of B and when it finds the right choice It will assign the value of column 9 to a third matrix C (Same size as A).

The problem is that I don't know how to work with index in Python, I took a look on the internet and found nothing to help me. I'm trying to access the neighbors of an element using things like (i+1,j), (i-1,j), (i-1,j+1)... I'm getting out of bound errors.

I was looking for something like this:

```
for i in A:
   for y in B:
     if A[i-1,j+1] == B[1,y]:
        if A[i,j+1] == B[2,y]:
          if A[i+1,j+1] == B[3,y]:
            if A[i-1,j] == B[4,y]:
              if A[i+1,j] == B[5,y]:
                if A[i-1,j-1] == B[6,y]:
                  if A[i,j-1] == B[7,y]:
                     if A[i+1,j-1] == B[8,y]:
                         C[i] = B[9,y],
```

Please, someone can give me some tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Edit:

To be more clear, let's say that both arrays A and B have the following format. No matter if the array A is 1D or 2D because I can reshape it. Each row of array B represents a neighboring condition and the ninth column is the value that should be assigned to array C if the condition on that row is met.

```
 A = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0           B = 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0               1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0               1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
     0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0               .
     0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0               .
     0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0               .
     0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0               1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
     0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0               1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
     0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0               0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
     0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
     0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Specifically, I'm trying to find the perimeter of the shape made of 1`s.

Comment: I think I could help you a little better if you were to post a larger portion of your code.  Generally, though, you aren't going to need for loops when using numpy.  It has a lot of functions to help you avoid for loops because they are slow.  Most of the numpy functions actually drop to C to perform the CPU intensive tasks.

Comment: You're saying A is 1D, but you use 2D indexing. (I suppose it is indeed 2D as this makes more sense with 8 neighbors.)
Also, you are not iterating over indices, but elements in your arrays. You might want to take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html
Furthermore, Python is 0-based. That means you probably want to substract one from the indices 1 to 9 in accessing B. Also, the row index goes first in Python, so you probably have to swap you B indices.

Comment: @MiTz the way you defined your `A` matrix doesn't occur to me it is a `1D array`. Can you post an example of `A` and `B` arrays? It is not clear from your explanation and your attempt for coding what you are trying to do!!

Answer (score 0):

`for` inside Python does work in little different way than in C. Running (even in shell) some simple examples could help you a little

```
collection = ["cat", "dog", "horse"]

for animal in colection:
    print animal
```

As you can see `for` assigns to variable `animal` elements of the list, **not** their indexes. So in your example variable `i` is assigned `0` or `1`, depending what value given element is list have.

But still sometimes you would like to operate on indexes (as in your case), so lets change a little our example

```
collection = ["cat", "dog", "horse"]

for i in range(len(colection)):
    print "index: " + i
    print animal[i]
```

This time we also operate on elements of list, only the list if little bit different.  With [function `range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) we create list of integers, from `0` to length of our `collection`. In other words we create new list with indexes.  With those we can access elements in our original one.

With use of `range` you should  be able to move forward with your problem.